# putting screen away?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I've just installed screen, what a great tool!

But i'm having some problems.

CTRL-A K kills a screen
CTRL-D detatches from a screen

but what are the difference? both results in loosing the screen?

also, how do i put it way? if i were to open screen, start a application and now i just want get out of the screen (starting a feedpoller and then let it run forever).

screen -list should show and enable me to enter any screen so it must be a way to "quit" but not terminating the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the screen is detached using Ctrl-A D (not Ctrl-D as you write*), you can resume it using `screen -r`. So the workflow is something like this:

- `screen`
- Work work work...
- Detach (Ctrl-A D)
- Do something else (for example end SSH session)
- Pick up the detached screen (`screen -r`)
- Continue work

If there are multiple detached sessions, then `screen -r` will let you know and ask you to pick one.

(*) Note that Ctrl-D *may* end your session. Ctrl-D sends EOF if you have an empty line in your shell. This causes the shell to exit, which terminates the screen session. But the Ctrl-D itself has nothing to do with screen.

Comment: +1 'Ctrl-A' then 'd' is the bit that makes it work as needed.

Comment: is there another way to list screens? I've added a title to one of my screens, and there is no way to see the difference from the two other screens?

Comment: @Jason94: `screen -list`. Check out `man screen` for more :-)

Answer (score 0):

> also, how do i put it way?

That is detaching. By detaching from a screen you are keeping it running.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> does what you want, it detaches the screen from the terminal, but you can still start an app and then let it run forever, the screen is not killed so it's still running.

Comment: Ctrl-a d

    Detach screen from this terminal. (detach)

Comment: Fixed it, it was a typo.